# How to render different part of a framebuffer by several different frustum and viewport in QOpenglWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a big renderbuffer attached to a framebuffer, and I want to render different part of the framebuffer by several repeat steps. For example, render the bottom part of the framebuffer,then the middle part,and render the top part.My code looks like this:

```
class MyOpenglWidget::public QOpenglWidget{
paintGL(){   
    mat4 model_matrix;
    ... set model matrix...   
    mat4 projection_matrix;
    ... set projection matrix ...
    mat4 viewMat;
    ... set view matrix ...    
    glViewport(viewPort.x, viewPort.y, viewPort.z, viewPort.w);
    glUseProgram(renderProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc_m_render, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc_pv_render, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection_matrix * viewMat));
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);    
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_render);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, renderSize);
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject());
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, frameSize, frameSize, 0, 0, frameSize, frameSize,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_NEAREST);
}

class myMainWindow::public QMainWindow 
{
   MyOpenglWidget myWidget;
}

myMainWindow::myMainWindow(){
   ...other construct operation ...
   while(condition){
       myWidget.setFrustum();
       myWidget.setViewPort();
       myWidget.setVBOdata();
       myWidget.repaint();
   }
}
```

In construct function of `myMainWindow`, the while loop set frustum,viewport and render data for `MyOpenglWidget` , call `repaint()` to render the correct part, then repeat the steps several times until all parts are rendered. But I find that only the last part is rendered,how can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you don't *have* to use a renderbuffer, you can try a cubemap instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason is Qt won't allow repaint event being called repetitively in short time.So I write a private funtion that use `makecurrent()` to get context and drawing off screen,then call `donecurrent()`.It works well.